# Drupal Image attach path in view using Customfield "PHP code"

Tags: image, drupal, path, view

I created a View that gets the title, body and attached image of some Story nodes. I need to use the Customfield "PHP code" to customize the output but the problem is that it's only giving me the id of the image in an array like this:  [image_attach_iids] => Array ( [0] => 66 ). So, I it looks like it's giving me the id but I need the full path of the image also. Is there some function that I need to call to get the path?

thank you

Comment: Any reasons you don't load the image with the view?

Comment: Yes, I have specific HTML & CSS that I need to display it with and I can't get the image as a separate variable to display in my html as a <li>. So, I'm using PHP code to send the $data object to a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using fields, you can put the image as a field. Put it at the top of your fields (so you can use replacement patterns).
   Setup:
   exclude from display, select 'path to image' in the Format option, and then use the replacement pattern in your customField PHP
2. If you aren't using fields, you can build up the path in the node-[contenttype].tpl.php .
3. Pathauto module: use the function `drupal_get_path_alias($path)` to get the aliased path to the node. `$path = 'node/'.$node_id`